# Replace multiple repeating character to one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a varchar column, and each field contains a single word, but there are random number of pipe character before and after the word.

Something like this:

```
MyVarcharColumn
'|||Apple|||||'
'|||||Pear|||||'
'||Leaf|'
```

When I query the table, I wish to replace the multiple pipes to a single one, so the result would be like this:

```
MyVarcharColumn
'|Apple|'
'|Pear|'
'|Leaf|'
```

Cannot figure out how to solve it with REPLACE function, anybody knows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

vkp's method absolutely solves your issue. Another method that works, and also will work in a variety of other situations, is using a triple `REPLACE()`

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('|||Apple|||||', '|', '><'), '<>',''), '><','|')
```

This method will allow you to keep a delimiter between multiple strings where Mr. VPK's method will concat the strings and put a delim at the very beginning and the very end.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('|||Apple|||||Banana||||||||||', '|', '><'), '<>',''), '><','|')
```

Comment: this one is pretty awesome :)

Comment: @dfundako this is even more versatile, marked as solution

Comment: I love how this uses a character sequence that should never exist in your marshalled strings, if you're really working with those literals, should be encoded in almost all situations and never have `"<tag>"`.

Answer (score 8):

One way is to replace all the `|` with blanks and add a pipe character at the beginning and the end of string.

```
select '|'+replace(mycolumn,'|','')+'|' from tablename
```

Comment: thank you, it solves my case, but @dfundako's solution is more versatile

Answer (score 0):

**With SQL 2017 and above**

This were the first google result for a lazy-search concerning the general case of removing consecutive duplicates of an arbitrary character within a string, hence the very late response.  The following will 'compact' duplicate characters *within* a string and optionally include leading and trailing "problem" characters.

My particular use case is, separate to this reply, to convert all non-URL-safe characters in to hyphens, then compact said hyphens for the sake of prettiness and sanity.

```
DECLARE @Input NVARCHAR(MAX) = '------Some---string--with----------lots-of----duplicated--problem----chars--'
DECLARE @CharToCompact NVARCHAR(1) = '-'
DECLARE @ResultInner NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ResultIncludeOuter NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ResultInner = STRING_AGG(value, @CharToCompact) 
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Input, @CharToCompact) 
WHERE value <> ''

SELECT @ResultIncludeOuter = @CharToCompact + @ResultInner + @CharToCompact

SELECT @ResultInner
SELECT @ResultIncludeOuter
```

Produces

> Some-string-with-lots-of-duplicated-problem-chars

> -Some-string-with-lots-of-duplicated-problem-chars-